# freemaker: read template from different path using class loader

Tags: java, templates, freemarker

I have my `TemplateLoader` class in the path `src/main/java`
and my template files are located at `src/resources/template`

When i try to load template using below code

```
Configuration config = new Configuration(Configuration.DEFAULT_INCOMPATIBLE_IMPROVEMENTS);
        config.setClassForTemplateLoading(this.getClass(), "/");

Template template = config.getTemplate( "resources/template/test.ftl");
```

it gives following error :

> freemarker.template.TemplateNotFoundException: Template not found for
>   name "resources/template/test.ftl".

the file is present at the correct location. So how can i load this file use free marker?

Comment: Can update the example by replacing `Configuration.DEFAULT_INCOMPATIBLE_IMPROVEMENTS` with a concrete version? It's a bad practice that shouldn't be copy-pasted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `resources` only exists in your source code (it's a Maven thing), but not in the compiled project. So it should be `config.getTemplate( "template/test.ftl");`. However, it would be nicer if you use `config.setClassForTemplateLoading(this.getClass(), "/template");` and then `config.getTemplate( "test.ftl");`. The point of having a template root directory is to make the actual location transparent, and to prevent security issues where a template includes and hence exposes an arbitrary resource that's not a template.